Cant get my group to stop wrapping and in a smaller screen just become horizontally scrollable in bubble.io
I have a group for the headers on this page, but unlike the repeating group below it, I cannot get it to stop wrapping the headers and just become scrollable when the screen becomes smaller. Im new to bubble but haven't been able to find an answer to this other than chat GPT says i might not be upgraded to the newest responsive engine. Im pretty sure however that I am using the newest engine, there doesn't seem to be any option to upgrade. Here is a screenshot of the page where the headers are wrapped and the options available to me in the editor.

